# htaccess redirect not working with some browsers

Tags: redirect, https, cross-browser

here is the htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NCL]
```

the first rule checks if you have www , and if not redirects to the www + https, the next rule checks to see if the client accesses the website via https, everything works, except on opera, opera redirects me to https://www.domain.com/https://domain.com/  like it puts the domain + request uri in {request_uri}, and i can't seem to make it work.Any suggestions on how to make this work correctly?
Edit : 
IE is not working too.It just gives server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect is done by Apache, so Opera is not guilty in this error. I tested your rules and got an error:

```
RewriteRule: unknown flag 'NCL'
```

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: 10x :), how did you test the rules?i want to know how to debug .htaccess

Comment: I have error.log enabled in httpd-vhosts.conf for the domain:     ErrorLog "d:/www/site/logs/error.log", create /logs dir and Apache will write errors for you there. Plz, accept the answer if it's good.